# treeview checkbox readonly

Tags: vba, checkbox, treeview, readonly

I am building a treeview object which has checkboxes for each node and I need some of these checkboxes to be read-only, based on some criteria.

I have found the following, but an error is thrown.

```
Private Sub ProductTree_BeforeCheck(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewCancelEventArgs) Handles ProductTree.BeforeCheck
End sub
```

The error received is Compile error: exptected: end of statement . The error persists as long as I use the **Handles ProductTree.BeforeCheck** .  If I remove it, I receive Compile error: User-defined type not defined.

Probably should I use a references?

What is a another way to create a treeview where I can have either editable or readonly checkboxes?

Thank you

Comment: What's the error? What's the question? Please [edit] your post to clarify.

Comment: Wait are you in VBA or VB.NET? I removed the VBA tag because `System.Windows.Forms` is a .NET namespace, and `Handles` is VB.NET event handling mechanics. If you're in VBA then you need to be in the code module for that control; select your treeview control in the left-hand dropdown at the top of the code pane, and the appropriate event in the right-hand dropdown at the top of the code pane; the VBE will generate the event handler stub with the correct signature for you.

Comment: That error means that you have an unfinished statement in the code preceding that event. Most likely you're missing an `End If` or `End Sub` somewhere.

Comment: I am in VBA, in excel macros

Comment: the procedure is empty, I was testing for the moment if I am using the right one for what I need

Comment: If you're in VBA and write VB.NET code, it's not going to compile. Syntax is different.

Comment: It look like you found some VB.Net code and you are trying to insert it into a VBA module. That isn't going to work. You need to find a way to do what you want in VBA.

Comment: Yes. it is the first time when I try to do this, from here the confusion. 
Anyhow I have tried firstly with 
Private Sub TreeView1_BeforeSelect(sender as Object, e as TreeViewCancelEventArgs) _
     Handles TreeView1.BeforeSelect
End Sub

but I still receive the same errors

Comment: Okay, last time - read *carefully*: **`Handles` is a VB.NET keyword that doesn't exist in VBA**. I gave you the steps to create an event handler in VBA, 33 minutes ago.

Comment: Yes, I got the event handler, but not sure what to write inside of it in order to have the checkbox readonly. Private Sub TreeView41_NodeCheck(ByVal Node As MSComctlLib.Node)
End Sub.